# Read array counts in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a `String Array` of `['grape', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple']`.

The stored procedure will look like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetFruits(IN fruitArray VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

????

END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Questions:
1) How can I read the counts from the `fruitArray` variable?
2) How can I set to the string array: `fruitArray` as for-loop statement?

Comment: if you have time to post and format all this, you could've simply google "stored procedure array"